# Putting (many) points on a sphere so that none of the uncurved connecting lines intersect.

Tags: geometry

I was wondering about a procedure of putting points on a sphere so that when you draw (straight) lines through all the pairs of points, no two lines intersect.

Additional clarifications:

- $n$ numbered points on a sphere
- in every point, $n-1$ lines touch, which is ok
- between any two points there is an uncurved line (segment) connecting them
  (the lines "pierce through" the sphere)
- all of this in $\mathbb R^3$ with Euclidean metric
- what happens outside the sphere doesn't matter (but this one is optional)

Side question: what would be the maximum possible amount of points? Infinity seems to be a likely candidate, but which one?

And would it be possible to construct a formula which instantly returns the coordinates for any of the points?

Comment: If by line you mean ordinary line in 3-D, one should be able to have infinitely many points. In fact continuum many.

Comment: Assuming "lines" is in 3D, not something like a geodesic on a sphere, this is the same as asking that no four points be coplanar (assuming you discount when lines like $AB$ and $AC$ intersect at $A$, which will always happen). What application do you have in mind for this?

Comment: I believe you have to use transfinite induction to establish that you have continuum many.

Comment: Do you just want the line *segments* not to intersect inside the sphere, or do you also rule out two lines which meet outside the sphere somewhere?

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21470/subset-of-the-plane-that-intersects-every-line-exactly-twice

Comment: @MiloBrandt I don't remember exactly, for some reason I thought about this a long time ago, and now it just came to me again.

Comment: @par Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you think of an explicit construction?

Comment: Not explicit, I would use as first and second coordinates for all the points a collection of algebraically independent transcendentals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lines $AB$ and $CD$ intersect, whether inside or outside the sphere, then $A,B,C,D$ are coplanar.  To get a solution with a countable infinity of points, just choose a sequence $p_n$ of points on the sphere such that each $p_n$ misses the finitely many planes determined by points $p_j$ for $j < n$.

Comment: Do you think that it is possible to put "$\mathbb R$" points on it?

Comment: Yes, if you use transfinite induction.